# declaration is incompatible - CPP

Tags: c++

We are gettting this error: "declaration is incompatible with "void mivni::inOrderChangePlayers(mivni::genericNode *root, mivni::genericNode *group)" (declared at line 21 of "subPlayerNode.h")

in the line:
void inOrderChangePlayers(genericNode* root, genericNode* group)
in our cpp file

**SubPlayerNode.cpp**

```
#include "subPlayerNode.h"
#include "playerIdNode.h"
namespace mivni {
    subPlayerNode::subPlayerNode(int key): genericNode(key)
    {
        level = 0;
        pointer_player = nullptr;
    }

    subPlayerNode::~subPlayerNode(){}

           
    **void inOrderChangePlayers(genericNode* root, genericNode* group)**
    {  
        if (root == nullptr)
            return;
        subPlayerNode* left = dynamic_cast<subPlayerNode*>(root->getLeft());
        inOrderChangePlayers(left,group);
        subPlayerNode* r = dynamic_cast<subPlayerNode*>(root);
        playerIdNode* p = dynamic_cast<playerIdNode*>(r->pointer_player);
        p->setGroup(group);
        subPlayerNode* right = dynamic_cast<subPlayerNode*>(root->getRight());
        inOrderChangePlayers(right,group);
    }
   
}
```

**SubPlayerNode.h**

```
#ifndef SUB_PLAYER_NODE_H
#define SUB_PLAYER_NODE_H
#include "genericNode.h"



namespace mivni {
    class subPlayerNode: public genericNode
    {
        int level;
        genericNode* pointer_player;
       

        public:
            subPlayerNode(int key);
            ~subPlayerNode()=default;

            friend class playersManager;
            friend void inOrderInsert(subPlayerNode* root, int* index, int** players);

            friend void inOrderChangePlayers(genericNode* root, genericNode* group);
            friend subPlayerNode* SubPlayerSortedArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end, genericNode* root_players);


    }subPlayerNode;
}

#endif
```

would love to get some help on how to solve it!
thank you :)

Comment: Why do you define the destructor in the .CPP file if you have defaulted it in the .H file?

Comment: you are right. I removed it. the error is still showing... any ideas why?

Comment: What is the purpose of `class subPlayerNode: public genericNode { } subPlayerNode;`? Usually the tailing `subPlayerNode` after class definition is not needed.

Comment: Why do you have ** at the begin and end of \*\*void inOrderChangePlayers(  )\*\*

Comment: the ** is for marking the line we have error in and we removed the tailing... still we have the same error. any ideas why?

Comment: please show a [mre], do you have a object called `genericNode` defined in the same way as you do for `subPlayerNode`? You should use different names for objects and classes. With some unrelated fixes [I can't reproduce your error](https://godbolt.org/z/ebv8MroT9)

Comment: That's not a great error message, it can often be helpful to use another compiler.  The subPlayerNode class does not have a default constructor.  So to create a variable of it, it would have to be written as, say, class subPlayerNode: public genericNode { ... } subPlayerNode(42);  Fairly doubtful that's what you meant to do...